# Shiro with permission annotation not working

Tags: shiro

now，i can check permission with java code correctly (like below):

```
subject.isPermitted("queryPrinter")
```

But if i make it in annotation ,it's fail.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequiresPermissions("test::home")
@RequiresAuthentication
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/permission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object testPermission() {
    return PdMDMResultUtil.createSuccess();
}
```

This is my shiro configuration in applicationContext-shiro.xml

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="${sso.server.url}"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="${upms.successUrl}"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="${upms.unauthorizedUrl}"/>
    <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="authc" value-ref="upmsAuthenticationFilter"/>
            <entry key="permission" value-ref="upmsPermissionsAuthorizationFilter"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /sso/login = anon
            /sso/logout = upmsSessionForceLogout
            /sso/** = authc,permission
            /** = anon
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="upmsPermissionsAuthorizationFilter"
      class="im.pudong.mdm.client.shiro.filter.UpmsPermissionsAuthorizationFilter"/>
<bean id="upmsAuthenticationFilter" class="im.pudong.mdm.client.shiro.filter.UpmsAuthenticationFilter"/>
<bean id="upmsSessionForceLogout" class="im.pudong.mdm.client.shiro.filter.UpmsSessionForceLogoutFilter"/>
```

When i debug problem , i found that [debug screenshot pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyA8K.png) .It show the mappedValue

is **NULL** , but i expected **NOT NULL**. Why ??

```
public class UpmsPermissionsAuthorizationFilter extends PermissionsAuthorizationFilter {

@Override
public boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws IOException {
    return super.isAccessAllowed(request, response, mappedValue);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Robert, did you tried this step(https://shiro.apache.org/spring.html#enabling-shiro-annotations) from Shiro documentation?